# Replace image by another using css display and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, display

I'm trying to apply the same effect on the social network logo: https://www.pierrejacobson.com/

Instead of using CSS awesome, I would like to do it with an image but it doesn't work as expected.

Regarding CSS, there is no need to put the code here. I just have the three social network logo on `display: none;`.

Could you please help me?

```html
<div id="social_bar">
    <div class="width_size">        
        <img alt="image enveloppe" class="email" src="email.png" />
        <p>CONTACT@PIERREJACOBSON.COM</p>
        <div id="network_logo">
            <img alt="logo_facebook" id="fixed_facebook" src="facebook.png" />
            <img alt="logo_youtube" id="fixed_youtube" src="youtube.png" />
            <img alt="logo_instagram" id="fixed_instagram" src="instagram.png" />
            <img alt="logo_facebook" id="facebook" src="facebook_blue.png" />
            <img alt="logo_youtube"  id="youtube" src="youtube_blue.png" />
            <img alt="logo_instagram"  id="instagram" src="instagram_blue.png" />
        </div>

        <!--network_logo-->
    </div>

    <!--width_size-->
</div>

<!--social_bar-->
<div id="logo_bar">
    <div class="width_size">
        <img alt="logo" src="logo-pierre-jacobson2.png" />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="30" value="RECHERCHER..." />
        <img alt="search" src="search-solid.svg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
const get_img = function(name){ return document.getElementById(name); };

const img_one = get_img("fixed_facebook");
const img_two = get_img("fixed_youtube");
const img_three = get_img("fixed_instagram");
const img_facebook = get_img("facebook");
const img_youtube = get_img("youtube");
const img_instagram = get_img("instagram");

img_one.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    img_one.style.display = "none";
    img_facebook.style.display = "inline";
});
img_two.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    img_two.style.display = "none";
    img_youtube.style.display = "inline";
});
img_three.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    img_three.style.display = "none";
    img_instagram.style.display = "inline";
});
img_one.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    img_one.style.display = "inline";
    img_facebook.style.display = "none";
});
img_two.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    img_two.style.display = "inline";
    img_youtube.style.display = "none";
});
img_three.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    img_three.style.display = "inline";
    img_instagram.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from display "none" to "inline" there is no transition. Instead try to use "opacity: 0" and "opacity: 1" and set the "transition: all 0.2s ease";

Comment: Ok I'll try this :)

Answer (score 0):

**The Display Property:**

In your initial question you say that you want to use the **display** property to hide and show your images, **however**, you also state that you would like to have the screens *transition* from one to another.

Transitioning is definitely possible through the aptly named CSS `transition` property

The problem is that the **display** property is not able to be animated. If an element is configured to `display: none;` the page is **immediately** repainted with that element removed.

This means that you need to use a different property, and we typically would use `opacity` or `visibility`. Here are the differences between these three:

- `display: none;`

  - *immediately* collapses the element
  - removes the element from view.
  - There's no transition allowed.
- `visibility: hidden;`

  - Does not collapse the element

    - The space it occupied is blank.
  - removes the element from view
  - Transitions are allowed

    - The element will still *pop* out of sight.
- `opacity: 0;`

  - Does not collapse the element

    - The space it occupied is blank.
  - removes the element from view
  - Transitions are allowed.

    - The element will fade until it is not visible.

Here is an example of the different way these properties affect the layout of the page:

```js
const context = document.querySelector("#examples");

const ele = context.querySelector.bind(context),
      hide = section => section.classList.toggle("hide"),
      onClickHide = (btn, section) => btn.addEventListener("click", () => hide(section));

  opacity = ele(".opacity"),
  opacity_button = ele("#oBtn"),
  
  visibility = ele(".visibility"),
  visibility_button = ele("#vBtn"),
  
  display = ele(".display"),
  display_button = ele("#dBtn"),
  
  toggle_button = ele("#tBtn");
  

onClickHide(opacity_button, opacity);
onClickHide(visibility_button, visibility);
onClickHide(display_button, display);

toggle_button
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(opacity); 
  hide(visibility);
  hide(display);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#examples {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#examples section {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#examples section.hide {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#examples section.opacity {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.opacity.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

#examples section.visibility {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.visibility.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#examples section.display {
display: block;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.display.hide {
color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main id="examples">
  <section class="opacity">opacity <button id="oBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr />
  <section class="visibility">visibility <button id="vBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr />
  <section class="display">display <button id="dBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr/>
  <button id="tBtn">Toggle All</button>
</main>
```

**Note:** In the above there are actually two properties transitioning - `opacity`, `visibility`, or `display` - **and** `border-radius`. You should notice firstly how in the `display` example the `border-radius` change isn't seen *at all*, and secondly how the `display` example is the only one that collapses the element so that it no longer takes up space.

---

### Applying Transitions:

By combining `opacity: 0;` with `height: 0px; width: 0px;` we can remove the element visually from the page while also removing any impact it has on other elements - meaning that it **won't take up space** and **is transitionable**.

However, in your particular case ( wanting to change the image to a different color ), all of that isn't necessary. You can swap out your `img` tags for `div` tags, then apply the background-url property to get an image (a.e. `background-url: url("facebook.png");` ) and a `hover` effect that adds whatever `background-color` you're looking for.

```
#facebook {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;

background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50");
cursor: pointer;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#facebook:hover {
    background-color: darkblue;
    background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

**Note:** You can also adjust `background-blend-mode` to other options to change how the image and the color are put together. a.e. `background-blend-mode: luminosity;` will make the color lighter `background-blend-mode: color-dodge;` will make it darker and add "dodge" effect. Feel free to play around!

```css
#facebook {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50");
cursor: pointer;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#facebook:hover {
    background-color: darkblue;
    background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

```html
<div id="social_bar">
    <div class="width_size">        
        <p>CONTACT@PIERREJACOBSON.COM</p>
        <div id="network_logo">
     
            <div alt="logo_facebook" id="facebook"></div>
        </div>

        <!--network_logo-->
    </div>

    <!--width_size-->
</div>
```